# How to place extended toolbar's title adjacent to the back arrow?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I have an extended `Toolbar` but it's title is getting placed at the centre like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/appbar_height"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**How can I** place this title adjacent to the back arrow up there?

Please let me know.

Comment: Well, You need to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` And this is not a good idea to do that and extending the `Toolbar` like that

Comment: but this is not a scrollable activity... the toolbar should remain of this size only.

Comment: It can't be like that, At least, Add an `ImageView`( Or a view with green color) without any effects and just, Let the `Toolbar` do his job :)

Comment: isn't there anyway of placing this title at the position I want?

Comment: **Custom** `Toolbar` with placing a `TextView` right there then hiding the `Toolbar` title maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="270dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:text="Toolbar Title" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Or, Remove the `android:text` then set the title :

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` to remove the already given title from the toolbar.

Comment: @HammadNasir I thought the same but what about that setting the 'Toolbar' on 'TextView'? Or you are trying to just removing the Title at all?